# Does Project update Documents array when they change?

Tags: roslyn

I have instantiated `project` variable like this:

```cs
MSBuildLocator.RegisterDefaults();
var workspace = MSBuildWorkspace.Create();
var project = workspace.OpenProjectAsync(csprojFilePath).Result;
```

A couple of days ago I was sure the `project.Documents` array was getting updated when they'd get edited, but now when I read the source of a specific document, after an edit, the source is out-of-date.

Am I remembering incorrectly or could something else be making this not work?

**Edit**: Based on this [discussion](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/7842) it won't update on its own. Probably hadn't tested it that carefully.

Comment: When you say "after an edit" do you mean changing files on disk, or using the APIs to change the contents?

Comment: @JasonMalinowski On disk